# Rubyのordメソッドは何の略称ですか？

Tags: ruby

rubyの`String#ord`メソッドが何かの略称だと思うのですが探しても見つかりませんでした。
`order`などでしょうか？

`codepoint`の方がしっくり来る気がするのですが、
メソッドの振る舞いを正確に理解できてないだけかもしれません。

`ord`は何の略で何故そう決まったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rubyでordが採用された経緯そのものは直接には知りませんが、文字からそのコードを求める操作をordと呼ぶのは歴史が長いです。COBOLや初期のBASICにありましたし、PythonやPerlに備わっているのもその流れだと思います。

codepointは文字符号化の方からの用語ですが、本来は符号化文字の位置を特定する情報という意味なので、1次元のスカラ値とは限らないです(例えばJISの区点コードは2次元と言うこともできます。区と点をつなげちゃえばスカラ値として扱うこともできますが)。現代ではまずUnicode codepointを思い浮かべるでしょうから曖昧さは少ないと思いますし、これからの言語ならcodepointの方がわかりやすいかもしれません。

Comment: もっと古くから使われてる名称だったのですね。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 4):

なぜそう決まったかは判りませんが ordinal だと思います。

Comment: ordinal「序数」ですか、なるほどありがとうございます！

Comment: `Return the Integer ordinal of a one-character string.` とのことです。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ord